# Leer multiples archivos txt en r

Tags: r, rstudio

Me encuentro abriendo unos 200 archivos txt's,lo que quiero hacer es abrirlos y al mismo tiempo irlo acumulando en una misma base, realice el siguiente código:

```
carpetas<-list.dirs(direccion)

hist_cancelaciones<-list.files(carpetas, pattern = "_C.txt")%>%
  set_names()%>%
  map_dfr(read_table, .id="Archivo")
```

pero me arroja el siguiente error:

```
Error in `map()`:
i In index: 1.
i With name: BERV_S202116_012_201_C.txt.
Caused by error:
! 'BERV_S202116_012_201_C.txt' does not exist in current working directory
```

¿Alguien sabe como puedo corregirlo?

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que `list.files(carpetas, pattern = "_C.txt")` retorna una lista con los nombres de archivos pero luego, `read_table()` necesita el path completo al mismo. por eso ahora te dice que el archivo no existe. Puedes solucionarlo así:

```
list.files(carpetas, pattern = "_C.txt", full.names = TRUE)
```